# Passing Data in wizard form without post back in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-wizard

Sorry for any mistake. I am new to MVC. I want to pass data from one wizard form to other in single view. Below is my controller side code which return list to view. In view there is wizard form where i make update some field in list and on next button i want to pass all changed data to next wizard form in table.

```
public ActionResult PlaceOrder()
{
 OrderDetail ObjOrderDetails = new OrderDetail();
 try
  {
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     ds = GeneralHelper.GetUserDocumentDetail(1);
     List<OrderModel> objOrder = ds.Tables[0].ToList<OrderModel>();
     ObjOrderDetails.OrderDetails = objOrder;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {               
            throw ex;
   }
     return View(ObjOrderDetails);
 }
```

Below is my view side Code

```
 <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="details">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h4 class="info-text">
                Let's start with the basic details.</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="persons">
                        <table class="table table-condensed table-hover" id="tblPurchaseOrders">
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    Product Code
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    SKU
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Product Name
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Quantity
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            @{ 
                            //To make unique Id int i = 0; 
                            foreach (var item in Model.OrderDetails.ToList())
                            {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(o => o.OrderDetails[i].ProductCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(o => o.OrderDetails[i].SKU, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(o => o.OrderDetails[i].Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(o => o.OrderDetails[i].Quantity, new { @id = "Quantity_" + i })
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            i++; } }
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr />

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="captain">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table class="table table-condensed table-hover" id="tbOrderDetail">
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Product Code
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            SKU
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Product Name
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Quantity
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is my jquery code.

```
$('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({
    onTabShow: function(tab, navigation, index) {
        if (index == 1) {

            $(".persons > table").each(function() {

                var fields = $(this).find(":text");
                alert(fields)
                var name = fields.eq(-1).val();
                var age = fields.eq(1).val();
                alert(name);
            });


        }

    }
});
```

I want to loop all rows of #tblPurchaseOrders and want to append all the rows to #tbOrderDetail where quantity is greater than 0.

Comment: *"I want to ..."* - can you explain exactly what's holding you back?  You've described a requirement, not a problem.

Comment: Jquery function not looping each row...

Comment: you're looping through the tables, try: `$(".persons > table > tbody > tr")`

Comment: ofc your table doesn't have the recommended thead/tbody, so you might need to skip the first row (or just add thead/tbody correctly)

Comment: Do you think it is good approach to loop all the row of one table and then append rows to other table. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below:

```
$('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({
    onTabShow: function(tab, navigation, index) {
        if (index == 1) {
            $('#tblPurchaseOrders').find('tr:has(td)').each(function() {
                if (parseInt(($(this).find('#Quantity')).val()) > 0)
                    $(this).appendTo('#tbOrderDetail');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

[**Online Demo (jsFiddle)**](http://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/x4k7yhye/17/)

Comment: can we add the button in row with row append. Also can we revert back row from #tbOrderDetail to #tblPurchaseOrders

Comment: I need your help on above... Can we do inline editing on row append to other table.